# Help showing derivative is compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

I'm struggling with proving the following theorem:

$\textit{Let }A:U\subset X\rightarrow Y\textit{ be a completely continuous operator from an open subset U of a normed}$
$\textit{space X into a Banach space Y and assume A to be Fréchet differentiable at }\psi\in U.\textit{ Then the}$
$\textit{derivative }A'_{\psi}\textit{ is compact.}$

I'm not sure how to go about this. I was thinking of trying to do it by contradiction, i.e., assuming that $A'_{\psi}$ is not compact, but I'm not really sure how to proceed from there... I guess what I am asking for is a hint or a strategy for trying to prove $A'_{\psi}$. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T=A'_\psi$. By the assumption, we have for some $\delta>0$,
$$
A(\psi + h) = A(\psi) +T h + \epsilon(h),\quad \forall |h|<\delta
$$ where $\frac{\|\epsilon(h)\|}{\|h\|}\to 0$ as $\|h\|\to 0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\psi =0$ and $A(\psi)=0$. Let $(x_n)\subset X$ be a sequence with $\sup_n \|x_n\|\le 1$. Our goal is to show that there exists a subsequence $n(k)$ such that $
Tx_{n(k)}
$ is convergent. By the assumption on $\epsilon(\cdot)$, for any given $\eta >0$, there exists (sufficiently large) $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that$$\Big\|\epsilon\left(\frac{1}{M}x_n\right)\Big\|\le \eta\Big\|\frac{1}{M}x_n\Big\|$$ for all $n\ge 1$. This impiles that$$
M\Big\|\epsilon\left(\frac{1}{M}x_n\right)\Big\|\le \eta\|x_n\|\leq \eta.
$$ 
Now, observe that by the assumption that $A$ is completely continuous, (i.e. every bounded sequence $(u_n)$ admits a subsequence that makes $A(u_{n(k)})$ norm-convergent in $Y$) the diagonalization method gives us a subsequence $n(k)$ such that for each $j=1,2,\ldots$, the sequence
$$
A\left(\frac{1}{j}x_{n(k)}\right)
$$ converges to some $y_j\in Y$.
From the fact that$$
A\left(\frac{1}{M}x_n\right) = \frac{1}{M}Tx_n+\epsilon\left(\frac{1}{M}x_n\right),
$$ it follows
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\|Tx_{n(k)}-My_M \|&=& \Big\|MA\left(\frac{1}{M}x_{n(k)}\right)-My_M-M\epsilon\left(\frac{1}{M}x_{n(k)}\right)\Big\|\\
&\le&M\Big\|A\left(\frac{1}{M}x_{n(k)}\right)-y_M\Big\|+\eta.
\end{eqnarray}$$ By taking $k\to\infty$, we get
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty}\|Tx_{n(k)}-My_M \|\le \eta
$$ and
$$
\limsup_{k,l\to\infty}\|Tx_{n(k)}-Tx_{n(l)} \|\le 2\eta.
$$Since $\eta>0$ was arbitrary, This proves that $Tx_{n(k)}$ is Cauchy in $Y$. Thus $Tx_{n(k)}$ is convergent, and the compactness follows as a result.

Comment: Very good answer, but can you please spend a couple more words on the fact that $A(x_n)\to 0$? To me, a completely continuous operator is a continuous operator that maps bounded sets to compact sets. Is it the case that this operator is weak-norm continuous? Thank you.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm sorry for the confusion, sir ... I've looked up precise definition of completely continuous operators, and it turns out that I used the wrong definition that $A$ sends weakly converging sequence to norm convergent sequence. Now, I edited my answer according to the correct definition that you gave. I appreciate your comment!

Comment: The previous version of the answer was also very good, I was asking out of my ignorance.

Comment: @James Note that $A$ is not assumed to be a linear map. We are dealing with a possibly non-linear, Frechet differentiable function $A:U\to Y$. But its derivative $A'$ is of course linear. About the definition: if $A$ linear (which is not suitable for our case), '$A$ sending weakly convergent sequence to norm-convergent sequence' is the definition of completely continuous function. And it is in general stronger than the compactness of $A$ which is saying 'every bounded set is mapped to a relatively  compact via $A$'.

Comment: @James However, for a non-linear map $A$, I found in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-015-9986-3_3
that the definition of complete continuity is more like that of compactness of a linear operator. It probably is more universally accepted definition, but I'm not sure.
The proof I gave is based on this weaker assumption, and should also be true under the alternative definition.

Comment: @Song Thank you for the help! It's funny you mention the possibility of $A$ not being a linear map, because the theorem is from a section about nonlinear operators so what you have found is very useful! 

Would you mind if I ask you some questions regarding the proof you just provided?

Comment: @James I don't mind :)

Comment: @Song Cool! It's been a while since I've encountered them, but is $\epsilon(h)$ an epsilon function? Furthermore, I get that you can assume $\psi=0$, but how can you assume $A(\psi)=0$? I have more questions, but I believe they come from me not knowing the answer to these questions :)

Comment: @James Umm .. I'm not very familiar with this terminology, but $\epsilon(h)$ can be seen as a formal expression of $A(\psi+h) = A(\psi) +A'_\psi h + \mathcal{o}(h)$. ($o(h)$ is $Y$-valued.) I don't know if it is sometimes called epsilon function .. We may assume $A(\psi)=0$ by considering $B(x) = A(x) -A(\psi)$ istead of $A$. Then $B'_\psi=A'_\psi$ is not influenced while we get $B(\psi)=0$.

Comment: @Song I'm not sure I follow why the $\epsilon(h)$ is needed and how it works when you use it throughout the proof. I get the idea of how you are trying to show $A'_{\psi}$ is compact, but I just can't connect the pieces.

Comment: @James Umm ... $\epsilon(h)$ is an error happening when we approximate $$A(\psi+h) \sim A(\psi) + A'_\psi h.$$ You can recall the the formula from multivariate calculus : for differentiable $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $$F(x+v) = F(x) + DF_x v +\epsilon(v)$$ where $\epsilon(v) = o(|v|)$. This error cannot be removed completely, but the idea is that if we "telescope"(I'm not sure this terminology is appropriate) by selecting large $M$, we can make it as small as we want.

Comment: @Song Thanks for the response! I think I need to read more into $\epsilon(h)$, cause I haven't seen nor used that before. But I think see the idea in your proof of showing $A'_{\psi}$.